# Thread not returning all subscribed users

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

**About**

I am using Laravel 5.8 with MySQL. I have a thread table and thread details table. I am fetching all records from threads and it's associated from threaddetails table wherever there are matching user_id found in threaddetails.

**Expected**

It should return all my thread and subscribed users present in the thread.

**Current**

It returns all my threads but from threaddetails table it returns my records only. It does not returns other subscribed users with which I am chatting.

**Question:**

Am I missing anything in **Query to fetch the data** section?

**Table: Thread - Schema**

```
Schema::create('tblthread', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedMediumInteger('thread_id')->autoIncrement();
    $table->timestamp('created_on');
});
```

**Table Thread Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO tblthread (thread_id, created_on) VALUES
(1, '2019-08-07 20:30:54');
```

**Table Thread Details**

```
Schema::create('tblthreaddetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedMediumInteger('thread_detail_id')->autoIncrement();
    $table->unsignedMediumInteger('thread_id');
    $table->unsignedMediumInteger('user_id')->nullable();

    $table->foreign('thread_id')->references('thread_id')->on('tblthread')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Sample Data - Thread Details**

```
INSERT INTO `tblthreaddetails` (`thread_detail_id`, `thread_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 6);
```

**Query to fetch the data**

```
ThreadModel::with(["Details" => function($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where("user_id", $user_id);
}])->get();
```

**Thread Model**

```
class ThreadModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblthread';
    public $primaryKey = 'thread_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Details() {
        return $this->hasMany("\ThreadDetailsModel", "thread_id", "thread_id");
    }
}
```

**Thread Details Model**

```
class ThreadDetailsModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblthreaddetails';
    public $primaryKey = 'thread_detail_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: You have this where on the query: `where("user_id", $user_id);` it filter the Details with the user_id = $user_id

Comment: Yes sir. Actually, I used that to make sure that I get only my threads. In addition to this, I want to retrieve all users present in my thread. But, it returns only my record in my thread. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: IMHO you are filtering the Detail model not the Thread model. Also for what I understand the primaryKey of ThreadDetailsModel should be `thread_detail_id`. You can debug your query, just add `->toSql()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the question. I by mistake, wrote wrong primary here while posting the question. It is correct in my code and the subscribed users are present in details table. That's why I was also checking to pick only my threads. Can u please suggest what should be done to pick all users from my thread?

Comment: Please define what you mean when to talk of `your Thread`.The Thread model does not have any `user_id` so does not belong to anyone

Comment: From my thread, I meant, all those threads which were created by me or in which I was sent message and somebody else created it. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand how can you recognize your Threads, the Thread model has only 3 fields: id, created_at and updated_at

Comment: Can u please suggest what should be the correct table schema in this case? A thread can be created by me or someone else can create it and send me messages. So, I will need both kind of threads. I am presently keeping the thread users in thread details table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197646/discussion-between-pankaj-and-dparoli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**whereHas** solved my issue

```
ThreadModel
    ::whereHas('details', function (Builder $query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->with('details')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`tblthread` should be associated to a user. Hence you can define `user_id` column on it.

The query should look like this:

```php
ThreadModel::where('user_id', $user_id)->with("Details")->get();
// So first you get all the threads that belong to you
// and then get all details for those threads (only)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This won't work because there is no `user_id` in the `tblthread` table.

Comment: That's what I suggested to have `user_id` created on the `tblthread` model first. A thread must associate to the user who creates it. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: I get you, and your suggestion is right, but this doesn't solve the OP question :/

Comment: I think it does. I'm trying to direct him to a proper solution. He is opened to change schema of the table as he mentioned in his comments.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. In that case, you should include all those details in your solution in order to guide the OP on the right path.

Comment: I did already :) I mentioned about adding a new column `user_id` to the `tblethread` table.

Comment: @Pankaj did it help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
ThreadModel::with(["Details" => function($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where("user_id", $user_id);
}])->get();
```

This query will filter all the related `details` that only contain the `user_id = $user_id`. So, of course, only the details related to the `$user_id` will be returned. So, basically you are constraining the related models.. not the threads itself. So with this, there might be some Thread returned that doens't have any detail associated with the user `$user_id` which I assume you don't want...

Try this instead:

- Check if a `Thread` has at least one associated `Detail` that belongs to the `user_id = $user_id`.
- Load all the `Detail`s of those `Thread`s.

So this should work:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

// ...

public function myCoolMethod()
{
    $threads = ThreadModel
        ::has('details', function (Builder $query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
        })
        ->with('details')
        ->get();

    // ...
}
```

- With the `has()` method we are checking [relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).
 - With the `with()` method we are [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) all the related details of those selected `threads`.